# Azure blob shared key creation 403 error getting

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, rest, azure-blob-storage

I wanted to create Azure blob container using python code using shared key Authorization,

I am getting below error:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:9e524b5e-301e-0051-4aa4-45750000\nTime:2023-02-21T03:27:02.8384023Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'PUT\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Tue, 21 Feb 2023 03:27:01 GMT\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/blobmediapedevwus2/mycontainer\nrestype:container\'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>'
```

How to fix this?

Below is the python code:

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

# Set the storage account name and access key
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'vidyaflowerapp01'
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx"

# Set the container name
CONTAINER_NAME = 'test'

# Set the request method and version
REQUEST_METHOD = 'PUT'
REQUEST_VERSION = '2020-04-08'

# Set the request date
REQUEST_DATE = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

CANONICALIZED_HEADERS = f'x-ms-date:{REQUEST_DATE}\nx-ms-version:{REQUEST_VERSION}\n'


# Set the canonicalized resource string
CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE = f'/{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}/{CONTAINER_NAME}\nrestype:container'

VERB = 'PUT'
Content_Encoding = ''
Content_Language = ''
Content_Length = ''
Content_MD5 = ''
Content_Type = ''
Date = ''
If_Modified_Since = ''
If_Match = ''
If_None_Match = ''
If_Unmodified_Since = ''
Range = ''
CanonicalizedHeaders = CANONICALIZED_HEADERS
CanonicalizedResource = CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE

STRING_TO_SIGN = (VERB + '\n' + Content_Encoding + '\n' + Content_Language + '\n' +
                Content_Length + '\n' + Content_MD5 + '\n' + Content_Type + 
                Date + '\n' + If_Modified_Since + '\n' + If_Match + '\n' +
                If_None_Match + '\n' + If_Unmodified_Since + '\n' + Range + '\n' +
                CanonicalizedHeaders + CanonicalizedResource)
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY), msg=STRING_TO_SIGN.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

# Generate the authorization header
auth_header = f'SharedKey {STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}:{signature}'


# Set the request URL
request_url = f'https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINER_NAME}?restype=container'

# Set the request headers
request_headers = {
    'x-ms-date': REQUEST_DATE,
    'x-ms-version': REQUEST_VERSION,
    'Authorization': auth_header
}

# Send the request
response = requests.put(request_url, headers=request_headers)
print(response.content)
print(response.status_code)
```

above code uses shared key Authorization to make request, we have to replace access-key and storage account in order test

Current response: 403
Expected response: 201

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not using Storage SDK for Python?

Comment: @GauravMantri, yes, our storage vendor uses sharedkey autorization we are setting uo nginx cache, however they are getting 409 response, so I wanted to isolate nginx for now,  and make storage rest call directly and  try similar commands that our storage vendor uses.

Comment: Thanks. You are trying to create a blob container in your code, right?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes creating container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what @Gaurav Mantri said, You are receiving this as because the authorization headers are not correctly formed. After reproducing from my end, this was working fine when I replace both `Date` and `Content Length` with empty string while building the signature. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

# Set the storage account name and access key
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '<XXX>'
STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY = "<XXX>"

# Set the container name
CONTAINER_NAME = 'mycontainer522'

# Set the request method and version
REQUEST_METHOD = 'PUT'
REQUEST_VERSION = '2020-04-08'

# Set the request date
REQUEST_DATE = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

CANONICALIZED_HEADERS = f'x-ms-date:{REQUEST_DATE}\nx-ms-version:{REQUEST_VERSION}\n'


# Set the canonicalized resource string
CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE = f'/{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}/{CONTAINER_NAME}\nrestype:container'

VERB = 'PUT'
Content_Encoding = ''
Content_Language = ''
Content_Length = ''
Content_MD5 = ''
Content_Type = ''
Date = ''
If_Modified_Since = ''
If_Match = ''
If_None_Match = ''
If_Unmodified_Since = ''
Range = ''
CanonicalizedHeaders = CANONICALIZED_HEADERS
CanonicalizedResource = CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE

STRING_TO_SIGN = (VERB + '\n' + Content_Encoding + '\n' + Content_Language + '\n' +
                Content_Length + '\n' + Content_MD5 + '\n' + Content_Type + '\n' +
                Date + '\n' + If_Modified_Since + '\n' + If_Match + '\n' +
                If_None_Match + '\n' + If_Unmodified_Since + '\n' + Range + '\n' +
                CanonicalizedHeaders + CanonicalizedResource)

# Generate the signature
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY), msg=STRING_TO_SIGN.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

# Generate the authorization header
auth_header = f'SharedKey {STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}:{signature}'


# Set the request URL
request_url = f'https://{STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/{CONTAINER_NAME}?restype=container'

# Set the request headers
request_headers = {
    'x-ms-date': REQUEST_DATE,
    'x-ms-version': REQUEST_VERSION,
    'Authorization': auth_header
}

# Send the request
response = requests.put(request_url, headers=request_headers)
print(response.content)
print(response.status_code)
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: formating you code may be issue, it is completely pasted code answer

Comment: @sagar, you have initialized the variable date as `Date = REQUEST_DATE`. And while creating the string_to_sign, it is causing the problem. I have used `Date=''` and got the desired results. You can use the above code where I have replaced Date and content length with empty string to create the container successfully.

Comment: @swathi, not sure i am still getting same error, updated code in question, any configuration error like not allowing to use shared key in my storage side?

Comment: @sagar This is because of the Request version that you have mentioned in your code. The solution is with respective to the first update that you have mentioned i.e., `REQUEST_VERSION = '2020-04-08'`. looking at your recent edit I see you have changed to '2014-02-14'. Try changing version to 2020-04-08 or if you are trying with '2014-02-14' then Look at the document provided by @Gaurav Mantri and form the String_to_sign accordingly.

Comment: @swathi, i did changed the version to both same result

Comment: @sagar, I have updated the code now try copy pasting the same code by replacing with your container and access key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252017/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-and-sagar).

Comment: it works for diffrent account, however i am now getting different error for existing, but i should accept this answer

python3 test.py 
b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:77440ab1-e01e-000f-7ce0-459e3e000000\nTime:2023-02-21T10:35:09.1160088Z</Message></Error>'
403

Comment: @sagar, Looking at your error message `This request is not authorized to perform this operation`, you might not have enough permissions to create the container in your target storage account.

Comment: @swathi, for enabled all all network in networking section, it worked thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you are setting `Content-Length` value to `0` in `STRING_TO_SIGN` however the server is using an empty string when validating the signature (please look at the error details which tells you the string to sign used by server to verify the signature).

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#content-length-header-in-version-2014-02-14-and-earlier):

[image]

Please try by setting `Content_Length` variable to an empty string instead of `0`.