# Insert Entity in Azure table storage using Web Activity ADF- Authentication Issue

Tags: authentication, web, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

Currently, I am trying to insert an entity into an Azure table using web activity in adf,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity

but after multiple attempts, I keep getting this error:

```
"server failed to authenticate the request. make sure the value of authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
```

I have checked to make sure my sas token is correct multiple times along with the account name.

This is what my input looks like:

> [image: output]

Can anyone point out my mistake, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

- The error might be because that you have used the SAS token directly for the table and used it as Authentication. This might be the reason that authentication is failing.
- The Microsoft document you have given has this information. Navigate to Authorize requests to Azure storage -> Delegate access with a shared access signature and check there about the correct way to build SAS for authorization.
- This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516194/azure-blob-shared-key-creation-403-error-getting/75517595#75517595)  answered by @SwethaKandikonda is about a similar error message while accessing blob.
- You first have to build String_to_sign which would look like something similar to the below image (taken from [the Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas)).

[image]

- So, you have to follow a similar process to build Authorization header in order to make the API call successfully.